# How can I automatically retrieve a CSV file from web, save it in a directory, and access it in C#?

Tags: c#, csv

I am working on an application which has to retrieve data from a CSV file online
and display it with a click of a button. However, how can I automatically store
the CSV file in a safe place where I can access the information? I am working with Visual Studio C#.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you need to be able to access the CSV file's contents from your program, or are you just interested in launching it for the user in whatever the default application is on his PC?

Comment: I am interested in reading in the data in the CSV file as a string. I really just need to access it. The data itself is displayed in rows and columns on the web and I can only get ahold of the CSV file if I click on the "Download to Spreadsheet" button, which prompts me to save it in a directory. I want to bypass that step and get ahold of that data in CSV. Hopefully without having to download extraneous libraries.

Comment: By "online" do you mean that the CSV file is on the web? Only accessible via http?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the WebClient class to make an http request to the server for the csv file. It should read the whole contents as a string which you can then parse and manipulate at your leisure.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(VS.100).aspx

Use System.IO.File to write the contents to a file.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The FileHelpers are a free and easy to use .NET library to import/export data from fixed length or delimited records in files, strings or streams.

**The FileHelpers Library**
http://www.filehelpers.com/